# Installer generator API or using command line app?

Tags: java, installation, windows-installer

I'm developing java applications for Windows and I want to automate the installer generation.

Is there any cmd line utility or API to do that?

**EDIT**

The best alternative I've found is http://izpack.org , which builds installers from XML files. It seems that they have enough documentation to understand how to make a "IzPack XML File generator" or even build them by hand (for small projects) and automatize the installer generation. Any new suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: What tool are you using to generate your installer?

Comment: PackJacket, but I want something that could be automated, without any click or user interaction. The idela was to give a him a configration file with all the components that I want on my installer and call a cmd line utility passing that file or is content as application parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is useful : http://antigen.sourceforge.net/